# Conjugate gradient method for a Big Coefficient Matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-algebra

Well I want to solve a 2D homogeneous Laplace equation (Dirichlet BC.) in a domain with 256*256 grid point with CG algorithm.
[common CG Algorithm](http://komarix.org/ac/papers/thesis/thesis_html/img85.png)
I'm using MATLAB and it's so obvious that my coefficient matrix (A) is 256^2*256^2 that is out of memory and I can't even form it like a matrix.
What should I do?
What is the numerical technique when we want to do a CG-like method to a large general matrix?

*Note: A is 5 banded symmetric matrix

thanks

Comment: Have you looked up MATLAB's "sparse" function as a way to store only the non-zero entries in your matrix?

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I can't even form A to sparse it with that function.
it's  65536* 65536 and MATLAB array number limitation is 10000*10000.
But I'm sure there is tricks to transform  a sparse matrix into for example vectors but I don't know how!

Comment: No, you don't understand how this works.  You can format an empty sparse matrix and then fill in the non-zero entries in $A$ without creating a dense matrix of size 65536 by 65536.